# How to get true values and flanking falses in columns

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, slice

I'm wondering how is the easiest way to select all the True rows in a column and also the immediately flanking Falses rows of the set of Trues.

> TLDR; Extract all rows that are True, along with the False rows 1 above,
>   and 1 below every True rows.

This is what I mean:

`df`:

```
0     False
1     False
2      True
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10     True
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
15     True
16     True
dtype: bool
```

Then, after running the code, the results would it be:

`result`:

```
1   False
2   True
3   True
4   False
7   False
8   True
9   True
10  True
11  False
14  False
15  True
16  True
```

Comment: Any reason there's no `0 False` in the output?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you're asking, even though I declared a possible dup using jez answer.

Comment: So, they want all True values, along with the False-y values just above and just below.

Comment: I want to get all True values and the Falses up and down

Comment: I have no idea why jezrael's answer getting downvote @jezrael and other one getting the almost same answer getting upvote ?

Comment: @Wen Not me. But I think in contrast to the current answer it may have been overkill.

Comment: @Wen The answer were similar, but not equal. jez only used df.value.shift(-1) and df.value.shift(), which ommited the "inside" of the True values.

Comment: It was hard to understand the question without @coldspeed 's edit.

Comment: @IMCoins aha ok , that make sense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this does what is needed:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'value': [
    False,
    False,
    True,
    True,
    False,
    False,
    False,
    False,
    True,
    True,
    True,
    False,
    False,
    False,
    False,
    True,
    True,
]})

result = df[df.value | df.value.shift(-1) | df.value.shift(1)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
    value
1   False
2    True
3    True
4   False
7   False
8    True
9    True
10   True
11  False
14  False
15   True
16   True
```